# How to read books from Google Play Books on PC?

Tags: ebook

I have a few books uploaded on Google Play Books. Play Books isn't available in the country I'm in.

I can easily access and read these books from my Android app (although I cannot browse and purchase new ones) but I can't access them on my computer/phone browser.

Is there any way I can at least read the books I already own on my PC?

Comment: Have you tried to use Android Emulator for Android Studio/Android SDK. There are emulator images available with Play Store/Play Services. If the location is a problem also install a VPN app.

Comment: When you say "Play Books isn't available", do you mean you cannot access the website, or something else? Please clarify this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your books from a web browser. Here is the link: https://play.google.com/books

Answer (score 0):

There is no Windows app available, but you could go to the website and read it there.

Here is the article I found usefull.

https://www.epubor.com/read-google-play-books-on-pc.html

What I have personaly done is download WebCatalog to my pc, and install the app on there. It alows you to install android apps within that app.

https://webcatalog.io/en/apps/google-play-books/